# Android app not permitting cleartext traffic inspite of adding xml permissions

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to access a development server API using nativescript-vue. I have added all the possible permissions in the android manifest, but it's giving the error: JS: Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to url not permitted

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Here is the network_security_config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.xxx.xxx</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And here is the Nativescipt-vue code:

```
httpModule.request({
        url: "http://192.168.XXX.XXX:XXXX/func",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        content: data
      }).then((response) => {
        const result = response.content.toJSON();
      }, (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
```

Comment: Did you try a clean build after updating your manifest? Between just `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` should do the trick unless you want to allow clear text traffic only on specific domains which I haven't had a chance to try personally.

Comment: @Manoj, yes I tried doing clean builds. I also tried putting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line by itself, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you using Emulator / Device? Which version of Android you are using?

Comment: I found a solution. `tns platform remove android` and then `tns platform add android` did the trick. It was probably not reading the manifest. Thanks @Manoj for your help.

Comment: You did mention already that you tried clean build, guess you didn't understand the meaning of clean build initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who face the same issue, `tns platform remove android` and `tns platform add android` worked for me. It started reading the updated manifest after this.

Comment: Hey Teddomatic, I tried theses commands but I'm still getting the same error. No idea why my manifest file isn't being honored.

Comment: @SammyKumar, did you stop the running program before? Try to run it on an actual device, or restart your emulator is you're using one.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to **App_Resources -> Android -> src\main -> AndroidManifest.xml** add **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** go to the application xml section then do a **tns update resources** cmd.